# Записать скринвидео с приложения

Tags: linux, linux-mint

Как записать скринвидео с рабочего стола понятно (хотя и есть [некоторые проблемы](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/538689/178988)).

А как записать видео с окна, не являющегося активным, если поверх него есть другие окна? Думал о том, чтобы отправить его на второй рабочий стол (именно рабочий стол, не монитор), но при переключении между рабочими столами записывается активный в данный момент, а не тот, на котором была начата запись.

В идеале надо бы и запись звука ограничить только звуками, издаваемыми записываемым приложением, но это не критично.

Comment: https://obsproject.com/ ?

Comment: @donRumata, по описанию не похоже, но я попробую.

Comment: Ну так она и в файл писать может. На сколько я помню по описанию.

Comment: @donRumata, я там про запись неактивного окна ничего не увидел. Сейчас попробую.

Comment: @donRumata, хм.. Похоже, теоретически там такая возможность есть, но фактически с половиной окон просто чёрный экран. Не впечатляет. Ну либо я не умею его готовить...

Comment: Хм. Ну тогда есть ещё вот такой список: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_screencasting_software

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freeseer

Comment: @donRumata, а как его установить? А то что-то не получается: http://pastebin.com/cKs0C74D

Comment: Там пакетов для бубна как-то не собрали. Но зато можно установить через менеджер пакетов питона. Как сильно это загадит систему - хз. Лучше сделать бэкап или попробовать внутри виртуалки. По идее поставиться должно так: `sudo aptitude show python-pip && pip install freeseer`

Comment: @donRumata, всё равно нет: http://pastebin.com/Eb6MLWcK

Comment: Выше допустил ошибку. Надо `aptitude install python-pip`. Но я попробовал на чистой свежеустановленной 16.04 и у меня не поставилась эта прога. Так что видимо пока отбой с ней. Вопрос остаётся открытым. А `vlc` случаем не умеет захватытвать отдельное окно?

Comment: @donRumata, а vlc вообще умеет записывать?

Comment: @donRumata, воспроизведение экрана в vlc я нашёл... Как записывать, не понял. Как скормить ему окно, вообще не представляю, хотя и допускаю, что это возможно.

Comment: @donRumata, а pip у меня уже был, похоже. Но как запустить freeseer я так и не понял. Он как бы установлен.. наверное...

Comment: Не. pip - это менеджер пакетов для прог написанных на питоне. У того же руби это gem, а у js - npm. Ну и у меня этот пип говорил, что его надо обновить, а потом ещё раз а потом ещё что-то, а потом "ладно, прогу поставлю", но как её запустить я тоже не понял.

Comment: Да, я в курсе, что pip - это менеджер пакетов. Это я к show вместо install сказал. Он поставил freeseer - его папка есть в питонных пакетах. Но вот как его запустить, я не понял, потому что просто как команда он не работает, а в его папке нечего похожего на то, что запускать, я не заметил. Правда, я только в консоли смотрел, по именам файлов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OBS Studio](https://obsproject.com/ru/download) умеет записывать конкретное окно как в Linux, так и в Windows (в Win7 надо включить aero, в Win10 и так работает); на Mac не было возможности проверить. Надо просто в источники добавить захват окна и в следующем диалоге выбрать, какое именно окно следует захватывать (есть возможность выбора по заголовку окна или по процессу).

Comment: На мак работает - проверено)

Answer (score 1):

в vlc  можно указать координаты записи:

As for changing the area of the screen to capture - go to:
Tools >> Preferences >> (Select "All" for "Show settings") >> Input / Codecs >> Access modules >> Screen

And change the "Subscreen left corner" and "Subscreen right corner" to pick the top-left corner of the recorded section, and "Subscreen width" and "Subscreen height" to input the desired size.

взято https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=101510

Answer (score 0):

Kazam представляет легкий в использовании интерфейс для записи событий экрана и создания снимков экрана. Программа позволяет записывать видео с рабочего стола и одновременно несколько звуковых потоков, также позволяя управлять уровнями звука и записываемой областью экрана.
Имеется встроенная поддержка кодеков H264 и VP8.

Источник - http://compizomania.blogspot.com/2016/11/6-ubuntu-16101604.html

Kazam - https://youtu.be/ADPPpY6ZEI8

Registered 2010-07-08 by Andrew

A screencasting program created with design in mind.

Kazam is a simple screen recording program that will capture the content of your screen and record a video file that can be played by any video player that supports VP8/WebM video format.

Optionally you can record sound from any sound input device that is supported and visible by PulseAudio.

Where to get it?

Kazam is from now on available from Ubuntu Universe repository. Stable PPA is provided for convenience only, so you don't have to wait for latest releases to show in Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: пожалуйста, переведите ответ на русский язык, нажав [edit]